# High latency with dnscrypt-proxy

Tags: dnscrypt

I have been using dnscrypt-proxy for some time and the latency for responses I've been monitoring for months is typically several times slower than if I used google, opendns, cloudflare, or quad 9.

Is this typical?

My average response time with dnscrypt is about 500ms (1/2 second), whereas with others, it is generally around 100ms or less.

After my records are cached, this is a non-issue, but prior, it is a major annoyance to have additional latency that I think would be avoidable.

Comment: I assume you are using a dnscrypt server on another continent.

Comment: No, I'm using dnscrypt-proxy 2.0 and it automatically selects the closest / fastest mirror available which is in the same continent.  The ping to the mirror itself is < 30 ms generally, but for me my response times (unbound through dnscrypt-proxy) are generally 500 ms.